# Why do we need to use uncompressed files for development?

Tags: javascript, development-environment, production

I have been wondering why do we need uncompressed files for development and minified for production? I mean what are the benefits of using uncompressed files over minified?

Do they give you better error messages or is it just that if we want to look something up we can go through code of uncompressed files?

Might be dumb question to some of you but I never had habit of going through code of well known big libraries and if I am not wrong, very few people do it.

Comment: https://blog.stackpath.com/glossary/minification/

Comment: Are you talking about compression or minification?

Comment: Yes, they give you better error messages and debugging. (You *can* use source maps to get these benefits to an extent on minified code.) They’re also a bit faster to modify because the minification step takes time. If you have no other build steps, that lets you skip a build entirely.

Comment: @Ry thanks for your answer, it clarified my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for this is usability. When a js-file is minified and you've got an Error and trying to find a place where it is located, what would you find? just a minified string like

```js
(function(_){var window=this,document=this.document;var ba,ea,fa,ha,la,na,oa,pa,qa,sa,ra,ta,wa,xa,za,Aa,Da,Ea,Fa,Ga,Ia;ba=function(a){return function(){return _.aa[a].apply(this,arguments)}};ea=function(a){return ca(_.p.top,a)||ca(da(),a)};_.aa=[];fa="function"==typeof Object.create?Object.create:function(a){var b=function(){};...
```

and so on. Is it readable for you? I don't think so. It's not readable at all.

For a much better understanding of the code, you need to uncompress it. It will add some additional spaces and format the code in a much readable way. so it would look like:

```js
(function(){
  var b = j(),
      c = k (b);
})();
```

It allows you to move from one piece of code to another and discover the code or search your error inside.

Also, for production, you need not only minify your code but compress it as well. So, it would be nice to use `Uglify` library for that.
It removes unnecessary spaces, rename variables, objects and functions for much smaller names like `a` or `b12`. It increases downloading speed.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

There may be several reasons why one might prefer uncompressed [unminified] files during development. Some reasons I can think of:

1. Reduce time to view changes while coding by skipping the minification step. (If you use minification as a part of your build step during development, you may have to wait for the minification to complete each time you make a change to see it in the browser.)
2. If code mangler is being used, variables may be renamed and not intuitively apparent as to what they are actually called in the codebase
3. If you are using webpack or some similar module loader, it may include extra code for hot module reloading and dependency injection/error tracking when not minified (which you wouldn't want in production)
4. It allows debugging to be easier, readable and intuitive.
5. Minification and code mangling are done MAINLY to make the delivery of those assets more efficient from the server to an end user (client). This ensures that the client can download the script fast and also reduces the cost for the website/business to deliver that script to the user. So this can be considered an extra unnecessary step when running the code during development. (The assets are already available locally so the extra payload cost is negligible)

TLDR: Minification and code mangling can be a time consuming process (especially when we are generating map files etc) which can delay the time between changes and the time those changes are visible on the local instance. It can also actually hamper development by making it harder/less intuitive to debug